# Netlogo, changing exported file name

Tags: netlogo

**I am trying to write information to a file for some experiments. Is it possible to change the file name for each experiment without having to change the code each time?

I was trying to use a slider to change the file name but had no luck.
**

Comment: It is certainly possible.  But do you have a system you would like to follow in naming the files?  Are you running these experiments under behavior space?  What distinguishes one experiment from another?

Comment: I am using the code you provided to me on my previous question, so i am opening a file and storing the information.
i was wondering if it is possible to use a slider to change the number at the end of the file.

Comment: @JackD You say, "I was trying to use a slider to change the file name".  Show us how.

Comment: `ask track-me [
    
    
  file-open "mytrack" + fileName + ".txt"
  file-print (list myMoveID pxcor pycor )
  file-close
    
]`

The slider name is fileName, it has values from 1 to 10, i was hoping i could write it in to the file name, in a similar way to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
file-open (word "mytrack" fileName ".txt")
```

`word` strings together its arguments and converts numbers to strings in the process.